# Supply a vector of colours to be used in ggvis grouped plot

Tags: r, ggvis

I would like to use `ggvis` to achieve what is answered by this similar question: [Colouring plot by factor in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721262/colouring-plot-by-factor-in-r)

Using the `mtcars` dataset as an example, and taken from [layers: Grouping](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/layers.htm):

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(cyl2 = factor(cyl)) %>% 
  ggvis(~wt, ~mpg, stroke = ~cyl2) %>% 
  layer_lines()
```

produces

[image: ggvis plot with default colours for factor levels]

with default factor colours given by `stroke = ~cyl2`.

**How do I change these default colours?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add a stroke scale:

```
... %>%
scale_ordinal("stroke", range = c("red", "green", "blue"))
```

Works with hex representations too!

```
... %>%
scale_ordinal("stroke", range = c("#fc8d59", "#aaaaaa", "#99d594"))
```