# Colouring plot in R by multiple factor

Tags: r, plot

I have the following `df` dataset:

```
  Subject Age                School TimeOfTest Score1 Score2
1       1  12 Aletta-Jacobs-College    Morning     78    180
2       2  11 Aletta-Jacobs-College  Afternoon     81    181
3       3  12 Aletta-Jacobs-College    Morning     79    177
4       4  13 Aletta-Jacobs-College  Afternoon     88    170
5       5  13    Marie-Curie-School    Morning     88    182
6       6  12    Marie-Curie-School  Afternoon     82    179
```

I want to plot `Score1` and `Score2` by both `School` and `TimeOfTest`.

Now, following the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721262/colouring-plot-by-factor-in-r) other question, I can get the color by one variable:

```
plot(df$Score1, df$Score2, col=df$School)
```

[image: Plot colored by school]

However, if I try to combine the two factors I get an empty plot.

I tried different solution but none worked:

```
plot(df$Score1, df$Score2, col=c(df$School, df$TimeOfTest))
```

Or

```
colors <- levels(interaction(df$School, df$TimeOfTest))
plot(df$Score1, df$Score2, col=colors)
```

Any ideas? Maybe without ggplot2 ?

Comment: `plot(df$Score1, df$Score2, col= as.numeric(as.factor(paste(df$School,df$TimeOfTest))))`

Comment: To me it seems like the `interaction` method works just fine.
`df <- data.frame(Score1 = 1:6,
                 Score2 = 1:6,
                 School = c(rep("A",4),rep("M",2)),
                 TimeOfTest = c("M","A"));

colors <- interaction(df$School,df$TimeOfTest);
plot(df$Score1,df$Score2,col = colors);
legend("bottomright",legend = colors,col = colors,fill = colors)
`

Comment: Yes, indeed interaction(...) works. I was using levels(interaction(...)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the following works:

```
colors <- interaction(df$School, df$TimeOfTest)
plot(df$Score1, df$Score2, col=colors)
```