# R: Legend color according to factor levels

Tags: r, legend, r-factor

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721262/colouring-plot-by-factor-in-r#comment97107107_7721594)
question where apparently the top answer is using an unsafe/erroneous way to add colors to a legend for a scatter plot.

Top answer suggests doing this:

```
data<-iris
plot(data$Sepal.Length, data$Sepal.Width, col=data$Species)
legend(7,4.3,unique(data$Species),col=1:length(data$Species),pch=1)
```

Comments suggest using `levels()` instead of `unique()` for controlling the text and colors in the call to `legend()`, but are unclear on why it would help. I would need a better explanation to trust that code.

How can I write code that guarantees proper coloring?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: That's true, I've rewritten it. Tell me if there is something else!

Answer (score 0):

A solution I've found is:

```
data <- iris
# Create a translation table that couple species to color
colorcode = data.frame(
  cbind(colorsMy = c("red", "green", "blue"), species = levels(data$Species)),
  stringsAsFactors = F)
# Make vector with colors for the different points in the scatter
iriscolors = sapply(data$Species,  # Species to colors translation acc to colorcode
                    function(x) colorcode$colorsMy[colorcode$species == x])
# Plot the scatter using the color vector constructed according the colorcode
plot(data$Sepal.Length, data$Sepal.Width, col = iriscolors, pch = 19)
# Since iriscolors according to colorcode, I can use colorcode for the legend
legend("bottomright", legend = colorcode$species, fill = colorcode$colorsMy)
```

This code is a bit bulky, but easy to follow and explicitly constructs correct color labeling in the legend. The "trick" is to create the `colorcode` variable that serves as a translation table between levels of the factor (iris species in this case) and colors for the legend.

Comment: Assignining iris to data is unnecessary, I think. Just use as is.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the top answer is that you're not guaranteed that `unique(data$Species)` and `levels(data$Species)` will produce the same order. They do in this example (setosa, versicolor, virginica), but might not in your data. The `levels` will be used for coloring and by default, they are sorted alphabetically, whereas `unique` will just list them in order of occurrence in the data frame.

I'll illustrate two examples where the given code will fail and how you can use levels to produce consistent results.

A) Re-arrange the order of rows in the data frame

```
data = iris[order(iris$Sepal.Width),]
```

If we now run the code as posted in the top answer, the colors in the plot are the same (black in the top left and green on the right), but the assignments in the legend are swapped (calls the black ones versicolor instead of setosa, ... ).

```
unique(data$Species)
## [1] versicolor virginica  setosa      # uses these in legend
## Levels: setosa versicolor virginica   # should be using these!
```

B) Remove instances from one factor level without dropping the level

```
data = iris[iris$Species!="versicolor",]
unique(data$Species)
## [1] setosa    virginica
## Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

If we now run the code as posted above, the black (setosa) points are labelled correctly (as setosa happens to be first in alphabet and first in data frame), but the legend shows red, while the points are green for virginica.

Now both of these issues can be avoided using `levels`:

```
plot(data$Sepal.Length, data$Sepal.Width, col=data$Species)
legend("topright", legend=levels(data$Species), col=1:nlevels(data$Species), pch=1)
```